# How to run parallel python scripts from java using the ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, python, parallel-processing, processbuilder, scheduledexecutorservice

this is my first question here.
I am trying to run parallel python scripts (that is multiple instances of a same script) from java periodically using the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. What i tried to do was using the ProcessBuilder class. To test the concept i have put first script into infinite loop while the second writes something to file and exits. Python scripts i need to make should be identical to each other so i tried to run these two from multiple instaces of a same class that implements runnable.

However the second script never starts. I managed to solve this by creating many classes that have exactly same runnable. But it seems highly impractical to have 10-20 classes that are same. So can i do this somehow within one runnable?
Here is the code that shows how i tried to run scripts using the ProcessBuilder:

```
public class TestScripts{

public static void main(String[] args){
       ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
       threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask1(), 1,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask1(), 1,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
  }


class MyTask1 implements Runnable{
public void run(){
     System.out.println("Task1 is running");
     ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Python27\\python.exe",
                                                        "C:\\Python27\\test.py");
     ProcessBuilder processBuilder2 = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Python27\\python.exe",
                                                           "C:\\Python27\\test2.py");
    processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Process process2 = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the line starting 2nd process:

```
Process process2 = processBuilder.start();
```

should be of course:

```
Process process2 = processBuilder2.start();
```

Besides you are scheduling 2 tasks, where each task starts 2 processes. So each 2 seconds there are 4 processes started (2x test.py, 2x test2.py). If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, scheduling only one `MyTask1` should be enough.

Comment: Ohh, that was exactly the cause of problem. didn't notice the typo! I needed to schedule n number of worker threads from the thread pool where each thread runs same script few times before next period. Thank you sir